# Unpredictible behaviour in c# dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic

I've found a bug (feature?) during learning dynamic in C#. Can anyone explain me, why do I have an exception??

```
static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic someObj = ConstructSomeObj((Action)(() => Console.WriteLine("wtf")));

        var executer = someObj.Execute;
        executer();         // shows "wtf"
        someObj.Execute();  // throws RuntimeBinderException 

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static dynamic ConstructSomeObj(dynamic param) 
        => new { Execute = param };
}
```

Note: typeof both exectuer and someObj is dynamic

Comment: What is the exception? And is it compile time or run time?

Comment: Looks like `dynamic` generates code to invoke method when it sees `obj.foo()` and generates code to access field when it see `obj.foo`. This really may be bug or at least unexpected behaviour

Comment: Probably type information of Execute method on someObj doesn't exists in runtime, since lambda has part of anonymous type and makes sense the contents of an anon type are not public. See similar problem on dynamic anonymous types: http://www.heartysoft.com/ashic/blog/2010/5/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic

Comment: Please provide the exception details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's look at following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("first");

        // works perfectly!!!
        dynamic foo = new { x=(Action)(() => Console.WriteLine("ok")) };
        foo.x();

        // fails
        dynamic foo2 = new { x=(object)(Action)(() => Console.WriteLine("ok2")) };
        foo2.x();

    }
}
```

`dynamic` uses reflection to access objects method and fields and since it cannot know exact types it must rely on type information present in objects on which it operate.

When field `x` in anonymous type is properly typed as delegate invocation `foo.x()` works because dynamic can see that field value is delegate.

When you use

```
static dynamic ConstructSomeObj(dynamic param) 
    { return new { x = param }; }
```

to create anonymous class you created class with field `x` of type `object` (dynamic is `object` behind the scenes). When you call `obj.x` dynamic sees that field type is an `object` and it does't bother to check to what exact type this field points. And since object doesn't have `Invoke()` method like delegates it throws exception. If you change method parameter type to `Action` it will work.

I guess this decision to check field type instead of type of value that field contains was taken to provide better performance. In other words when you check field type `CallSite` class generated by `dynamic` can be cached and reused later.

References:
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/ef407901f8fdd9ed8c377dbec8123b5afb932ebb/mcs/class/Microsoft.CSharp/Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder/Binder.cs

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/ef407901f8fdd9ed8c377dbec8123b5afb932ebb/mcs/class/Microsoft.CSharp/Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder/CSharpInvokeMemberBinder.cs

EDIT: Checked this on mono, can somebody verify on VS

Comment: Not sure what checking you wanted but running on windows your program does exactly as you described (prints first and ok and then throws an exception).

Comment: @Chris thank's, unfortunately .NETFiddle uses outdated compiler and currently I have access only to linux boxes

Answer (score 3):

ok, interesting. This 2 Lines would work:

```
Task.Run(someObj.Execute);  
((Action)someObj.Execute)();
```

It seems that the compiler does accept the () for dynamic types always and at runtime the CLR only looks 'one level deep'. So you can help here by adding explicit cast or do the cast implicit with the Task.Run(). If this is a feature or a bug!? ... no idea ;-) ...

Comment: .Invoke() also works, but I guess it's compiled to the same thing as one of your example